# QGIS: Function week(interval) does not exist

Tags: qgis, postgis, query

I try to query with an expression I found in older posts:

```
 week(age(now(),end_time)) <= 1
```

Where `end_time` is of `QDateTime`.

I am getting back:

```
An error occurred when executing the query.
The data provider said:
ERROR:  function week(interval) does not exist
                                                 ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I tried with `day` instead of `week` and got a similar result.

Could you, please, help we to find out where I have a mistake.

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using? How is end_time formatted? If you just put "end_time" in the expression box then does the preview look like <date: yyyy-mm-dd>?

Comment: I use 3.16.16. Where I can see preview?

Comment: Field format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 1):

`now()` is a fickle companion. The moment you query it, it already is gone. Nail it down firmly using `to_date()` and at least until midnight it wont change.

Or, in a less poetic manner of speaking: You need to hand two datetimes of the same format & length to `age()`. Force `now()` into the same format as your `end_time` and you'll be fine.

Comment: I don't need it as stable. I am interested in building a layer that shows the last week of events in days. That is why the exact moment would not be a big deal.